# How to establish convergence rate

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Could anyone tell me about the convergence rate of the following

$$ X_{n+1}= f_{\omega_n}(X_n)$$ where $f_1,\dots, f_s$ are finite number of bounded Lipschitz functions (with Lipschitz constants $L_i$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{s} p_kL_k <1$ )on $\mathcal X$, a metric space. 
$\omega_0,\omega_1,\dots, \omega_n,\dots$ are i.i.d discrete random variable taking values in $\{1,2,\dots,s\}$. $p_k=\mathbb P(\omega_i=k)$. 
It is given that a unique invariant probability measure exists for such a chain. Thanks for any help!

Comment: lmao ur bio description. anyways, "which also a question, which metric to use in this case to find the rate". didn't you say "wasserstein metric"?

Comment: I am confused by the answer below as well.

Comment: To begin with, assume just that you have a sequence of transformations such that the product of their Lipschitz constants decays exponentially and look at what this sequence does to any measure on your space. Then average with respect to the distribution of these sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f_k, k=1,2,\cdots,s$ are Lipschitz, $ \left\vert X_{n+1} \right\vert = \left\vert f_{\omega_n}(X_n) \right\vert\le L_{\omega_n}\left\vert X_n \right\vert  \le \cdots \le \prod_{k=0}^nL_{\omega_k}|X_0|$. Hence the ratio $X_n/X_0$ is bounded by
$$ R_{n} = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}L_{\omega_k} = \exp\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln \left(L_{\omega_k}\right)\right). $$

The ratio bound $R_n$ can be considered as the convergence ratio since the bounds can be achieved by simply letting $f_k(x) \equiv L_k \cdot x$.

Note $\ln \left(L_{\omega_k}\right)$ is i.i.d. with probabilities being $p_k, k=1,2,\cdots,s$. By law of large numbers, $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln \left(L_{\omega_k}\right)}{n}\rightarrow E\left(L_{\omega_k}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^sp_i\ln \left(L_{i}\right)\equiv R$ a.s.

Recall that $\ln(\cdot)$ is concave function. By Jensen's inequality, we have
$$ R\equiv \sum_{i=1}^sp_i\ln \left(L_{i}\right) \le \ln \left( 
\sum_{i=1}^sp_iL_i \right) < 0. $$
We further have $e^R=\prod_{k=1}^nL_i^{p_i} < 1$. Hence the convergence rate for large $n$ is
$$ R_n \approx exp(nR) = {\left( e^R \right)}^n={\left(\prod_{k=1}^sL_i^{p_i}\right)}^n. $$

Comment: Hi. How does this answer the OP's question about the convergence rate of the measures associated to the $X_n$'s to the invariant measure in the Wasserstein metric?

Comment: To begin with, assume just that you have a sequence of transformations such that the product of their Lipschitz constants decays exponentially and look at what this sequence does to any measure on your space. Then average with respect to the distribution of these sequences.

Comment: @mathworker21I have established that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. at the rate of ${\left(e^R\right)}^n$ and $e^R < 1$. It follows that the invariant measure is $\delta(x)$. The distance metric from the invariant measure is relatively easy to formulate. Feel free to complete the answer from here as I lack the bandwidth to get into the specifics. My guess is that the end result will still be something very similar to ${\left(e^R\right)}^n$.